# nodejs create a duplex stream from a readable and writable

Tags: node.js, stream

I'm working on the nodeschool stream adventure and got to the duplex redux challenge.

I solved the challenge using the duplexer module but wanted to solve it using native stream functionality.

Here is the solution using duplexer:

```
var duplexer = require('duplexer');
var through = require('through');

module.exports = function (counter) {
    var counts = {};
    var input = through(write, end);
    return duplexer(input, counter);

    function write (row) {
        counts[row.country] = (counts[row.country] || 0) + 1;
    }
    function end () { counter.setCounts(counts) }
};
```

So, it gets a readable stream in, and is returned a duplex stream.  I'm trying to solve this again with:

```
var duplexer = require('duplexer');
var stream   = require('stream');

module.exports = function (counter) {
    var counts = {};
    var ts = stream.Transform({ objectMode: true })

    ts._transform = function(obj, enc, next) {
        var country = obj.country;
        var count = counts[country] || 0;
        counts[obj.country] = count + 1;
        next();
    }

    ts.on('finish', function() {
        counter.setCounts(counts);
    });

    counter.pipe(ts)
    return ts;
};
```

When run as is, it results in no output at all, so I changed `next()` to `next(null, JSON.stringify(counts))`.  The stringify is because the next stream is not set to object mode.  I get output, but its wrong and it throws `stream.push() after EOF`.